# Aligning tikzpictures in columns for beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, two-column, columns

I need to have 2 columns on one frame in latex beamer.

I want both tikzpictures to be the exact same size (nodes should be equal size) and all the text on the same height, e.G. the definition of H should be on the same line as G and the definition of F' should be on the same line as F.

I can't figure it out somehow.

Any help appreciated!

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Satz 6}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={\textwidth}{\textheight},center}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[
                    state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2.5em}]
                    \node[state] (n6) at (1,10) {6};
                    \node[state] (n4) at (4,8)  {4};
                    \node[state] (n5) at (8,9)  {5};
                    \node[state] (n3) at (5,5)  {3};
                    %\node[state] (n7) at (2,5) {7};
                    %\node[state] (n8) at (-2,4)  {8};
                    %\node[state] (n9) at (0,1)  {9};
                    %\node[state] (n10) at (1.5,3) {10};
                    
                    % labels
                    %\node[scale=1.5] at (-2,10) {$G = H + T$};
                    %\node[scale=1] at (-0.5,5.5) {$H = (V_H, E_H)$};
                    \node[scale=2] at (5,12) {$H = (V', E')$};
                    \node[scale=2] at (5,3) {$F' = \{4\}$};
                    
                    %\foreach \from/\to [count=\xi] in {n6/n4,n4/n5,n5/n1,n1/n2,n2/n5,n2/n3,n3/n4, n5/n3}
                    %\draw (\from) -- (\to) node [midway, label=\xi] {};
                    
                    
                    \draw (n4) -- (n5) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n4) -- (n6) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n3) -- (n4) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n3) -- (n5) node [midway] {};
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{adjustbox}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={\textwidth}{\textheight},center}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[
                    state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2.5em}]
                    \node[state] (n6) at (1,10) {6};
                    \node[state] (n4) at (4,8)  {4};
                    \node[state] (n5) at (8,9)  {5};
                    \node[state] (n1) at (11,8) {1};
                    \node[state] (n2) at (9,6)  {2};
                    \node[state] (n3) at (5,5)  {3};
                    %\node[state] (n7) at (2,5) {7};
                    %\node[state] (n8) at (-2,4)  {8};
                    %\node[state] (n9) at (0,1)  {9};
                    %\node[state] (n10) at (1.5,3) {10};
                    
                    % labels
                    %\node[scale=1.5] at (-2,10) {$G = H + T$};
                    %\node[scale=1] at (-0.5,5.5) {$H = (V_H, E_H)$};
                    \node[scale=2] at (5,12) {$G = (V, E)$};
                    \node[scale=2] at (5,2) {$F = \{2\}$};
                    \node[scale=2] at (5,1) {$F' \cup F = \{2,4\}$};
                    
                    %\foreach \from/\to [count=\xi] in {n6/n4,n4/n5,n5/n1,n1/n2,n2/n5,n2/n3,n3/n4, n5/n3}
                    %\draw (\from) -- (\to) node [midway, label=\xi] {};
                    \draw (n1) -- (n2) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n1) -- (n5) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n2) -- (n5) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n2) -- (n3) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n4) -- (n5) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n4) -- (n6) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n3) -- (n4) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n3) -- (n5) node [midway] {};
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{adjustbox}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Satz 6}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,baseline=(current bounding box.north),
                    state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2em}]
                    \node[state] (n6) at (1,10) {6};
                    \node[state] (n4) at (4,8)  {4};
                    \node[state] (n5) at (8,9)  {5};
                    \node[state] (n3) at (5,5)  {3};
                    \node at (5,12) {$H = (V', E')$};
                    \node at (5,3) {$F' = \{4\}$};
                    \draw (n4) -- (n5) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n4) -- (n6) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n3) -- (n4) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n3) -- (n5) node [midway] {};
                \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
            \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,baseline=(current bounding box.north),
                    state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2em}]
                    \node[state] (n6) at (1,10) {6};
                    \node[state] (n4) at (4,8)  {4};
                    \node[state] (n5) at (8,9)  {5};
                    \node[state] (n1) at (11,8) {1};
                    \node[state] (n2) at (9,6)  {2};
                    \node[state] (n3) at (5,5)  {3};
                    \node at (5,12) {$G = (V, E)$};
                    \node at (5,3) {$F = \{2\}$};
                    \node at (5,2) {$F' \cup F = \{2,4\}$};
                    \draw (n1) -- (n2) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n1) -- (n5) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n2) -- (n5) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n2) -- (n3) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n4) -- (n5) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n4) -- (n6) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n3) -- (n4) node [midway] {};
                    \draw (n3) -- (n5) node [midway] {};
                \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!
So it is basically a combination of [t] for the Columns and scale+baseline for the tikzpictures? I get it :)

Comment: Additinally, I also slightly decreased the size of the circular nodes, removed the scale option from the eqation containing nodes, adjusted the y-coordinate of the node containing `$F = \{2\}$` and adjusted the widths of the two columns in order to allowfor a slightly larger scale factor than possible with equally wide columns.